# How to iterate over a formset in django?

Tags: django

This is my views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
def codepost(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form=CodeFormSet(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        datan = ""
        for forms in form.ordered_forms:
            data = forms.cleaned_data['code']   
            datan = datan + data
        return render_to_response('submissiondone.html', {'data':datan})
else:
    form = CodeFormSet()
    data1=QuestionBase.objects.get(pk=1)
    #form.append(data1.text)
    #data1 = mform.text
    csrfContext = RequestContext(request)
return render_to_response('quesdisp.html', {'form': form})
```

This gives an addition ORDER field which I don't want. So, how do I iterate over a formset? If I remove the can_order = true from the formset, then it is not recognizing "code" as a valid input.

Thus, how do I iterate over this?

Edit:
This is the formest part of my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

class CodeForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)


CodeFormSet = formset_factory(CodeForm, extra = 5, )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
formset = CodeFormSet(request.POST)
for form in formset:
    form.cleaned_data...
```

Comment: For django < 1.3 it's `formset.forms`

Comment: Data gets returned as a dict with no values in it.

Comment: As stated in my edit, it returns a set of forms. 5 forms with strings in it.

Comment: you should call is_valid before accessing cleaned_data